# VB.net Receiving error BC30201: Expression expected

Tags: vb.net

Im using this to declare a connection to a SQL

```vb
Public CONN As New SqlConnection("Data Source=" & My.Settings.SrvName & ";Initial Catalog=" & My.Settings.Catalog & ";Persist Security Info=" & True & ";User ID=" & My.Settings.USER & ";Password=" & My.Settings.PASSWRD & ";Integratedsecurity=" & My.Settings.InterSec & ";Connection Timeout=" & My.Settings.CnnTimeOut &)
```

but on the Closing ')' Im getting the error BC30201: Expression expected, this same method Ihave use in other proyects and works, can anyone tell me where my error?, please help.
Thanks.

Comment: Please don't post questions with unformatted code. Your code is hard enough to read already, without making it more so. ALWAYS look at the preview of your question and make sure it is as readable as possible before posting. If you don't now how to use formatting on this site, spend some time in the Help Center to learn.

Answer (score 0):

This is a fine example of why lots of string concatenation is a bad idea. Your code is hard to read - even for you, obviously - and so it's error prone. With all those `&` operators in there, you haven't noticed that you have one you don't need at the end, This:

```vb
& My.Settings.CnnTimeOut &)
```

should be this:

```vb
& My.Settings.CnnTimeOut)
```

You should avoid using multiple `&` operators in one line and instead use the `String.Format` method or string interpolation. In this case, don't use any of those options. You should be using a `SqlConnectionStringBuilder`, e.g.

```vb
Dim builder As New SqlConnectionStringBuilder With {.DataSource = My.Settings.SrvName,
                                                    .InitialCatalog = My.Settings.Catalog}

Using connection As New SqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString)
    '...
End Using
```

Notice that I have created the connection with a `Using` statement, which is what you should be doing too. Don't use a single, common connection. You can use a single connection string builder to generate the connection string, but you should then create, use and destroy connection objects where and when you need them.

Note that you can set as many properties of the connection string builder as you need to when you create it. I have just set two here for brevity.